# How do I prevent libserial to eat up characters like 0x0A, 0x0D, or 0x0F coming from my serial device?

Tags: c++, newline, libserial

When communicating with a serial-over-USB device (a GNS FM9 receiver for getting road traffic alerts) by using [`libserial`'s](https://github.com/crayzeewulf/libserial) `SerialStream` object, I found out that not all characters coming from the device are in fact being read. This is what I always get served:

```
3F 00 56 08 37 3F
```

When using the same device with the [RDS Surveyor app](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/RdsSurveyor) (which is written in Java and uses a `com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort`), the same response looks like this:

```
3F 00 00 56 08 0A 37 0C 0D 3F
```

After some research, I stumbled over this posting: [Wrong newline character over the serial port (CR instead of LF)](https://superuser.com/questions/714078/wrong-newline-character-over-serial-port-cr-instead-of-lf). The poster does not use `libserial` (but some ready-to-use serial port comm app), but his issue is exactly the same as mine.

This is the system-side config of the port in question:

```sh
pi@autoradio:~ $ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0; intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U;
eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0; -parenb -parodd -cmspar
cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr
-igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8 opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret
-ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh
-xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

The system is a Raspbery Pi 3B with the latest production version of Raspbian running. On the system-side, the device looks like this:

```sh
pi@autoradio:~ $ ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jun  7 17:11 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Now, my question is: How can I make my SerialStream read all characters without any transformations, just as they come from the port? I don't really wanna use `stty` in this context because its settings might get overwritten when removing and reattaching the device. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to add a tag for the language.

Comment: I've just done it, but at this point, the language itself does not seem to be relevant yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I [opened an issue](https://github.com/crayzeewulf/libserial/issues/162) with the maintainers of `libserial` and got the answer that the C++ `std::iostream` (NOT even `LibSerial::SerialStream`!) kicks out whitespace characters by default. CR, LF, and FF are regarded as such.

They proposed me this solution:

```
SerialStream tmc_receiver_handler ("/dev/ttyUSB0", ios::in | ios::out);
char c = 0x00;

tmc_receiver_handler.SetBaudRate      (SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_38400);
tmc_receiver_handler.SetCharSize      (SerialStreamBuf::CHAR_SIZE_8);
tmc_receiver_handler.SetFlowControl   (SerialStreamBuf::FLOW_CONTROL_NONE);
tmc_receiver_handler.SetParity        (SerialStreamBuf::PARITY_NONE);
tmc_receiver_handler.SetNumOfStopBits (SerialPort::STOP_BITS_1);

tmc_receiver_handler >> noskipws >> c;
```

`noskipws` switches off whitespace suppression. After applying this, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the port is in "raw" mode.

From a quick look at the libserial documentation, it seems it doesn't have a parameter to set a raw mode. Some options:

- Modify libserial to set raw mode.
- Don't use libserial, and use something else.
- Change the port defaults for your operating system.

The implementation of libserial seems quite basic; you are probably better off using something like Boost.asio.

Comment: First, I've got the information that the issue is NOT really `LibSerial`-related. See the answer below. Second, as the target system is an RPi, Boost would be a slight overkill. Sorry!